# Solving buying-selling optimization problem

Tags: algorithm, performance

Is there a better than O(n²) solution to solving the following problem:

On day *i*, the unit price of goods is B[*i*] and they can be sold for S[*i*] a unit. If you have 1 unit of cash on day 1, how much can you earn in *N* days with the constraint that you can never sell stock you don't have on the day?

Comment: Can you give full definition of the problem, please?

Comment: I believe it is the following problem. On day i you can buy goods at the price B[i] and sell goods at the price S[i]. If you have 1 unit of cash at the beginning of day 1, what is the maximum cash you can have at the end of day n?

Comment: Is this homework? In that case retag your question.

Comment: @Pedery: ["the homework tag, like other so-called 'meta' tags, is now discouraged."](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10812)

Comment: @Manish: Please clarify whether you have to buy and sell stock on a per item basis, or whether you can buy and sell parts of stock, i.e. continuous amounts.

Comment: @JPvdMerwe: Interesting. But I still assume it's discouraged to solve students' homework since wrapping your brain around complex problems is all part of the learning process. Just like stated in your link. I doubt any of us would have been here today if it weren't for a few sessions of forehead against brick :)

Comment: @Pedery: Agreed. Just thought I should pass on the new policy. :) And on a related note: "Programming, v., An action similar to bashing one's head against a wall but with less opportunity for reward."

Answer (score 0):

It can be solved in O(*n*), like this:

C[*i*] represents the maximum cash you can hold at the end of day *i*, and G[*i*] represents the maximum amount of goods you can hold at the end of day *i*. I'm going to suppose you start out with 1 unit of cash and no goods, but the algorithm will work for other initial conditions.

- Initialize: C[0] = 1; G[0] = 0.
- Repeat for *i* from 1 to *n*:
- Let the selling price on day *i* be S[*i*] and the buying price B[*i*].
- Set C[*i*] = max(C[*i* − 1], G[*i* − 1]S[*i*]) and G[*i*] = max(G[*i* − 1], C[*i* − 1]/B[*i*]).

Here's an implementation in Python:

```py
from __future__ import division

def max_cash(cash, goods, selling_price, buying_price):
    """Return the maximum amount of cash you can have, if you start with
    the given cash and goods, and on day i you can sell goods at
    selling_price[i] or buy them at buying_price[i].

    Cash and goods are assumed to be arbitrarily divisible.

    """
    for sell, buy in zip(selling_price, buying_price):
        assert(sell <= buy)
        cash, goods = max(cash, goods * sell), max(goods, cash / buy)
    return cash
```

Let's check this on some of the alleged counter-examples raised in comments:

- [JPvdMerwe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4128487/solving-buying-selling-optimization-problem/4128648#comment4463612_4128648) suggests that this case "breaks all greedy algorithms I can think of", but the algorithm above works fine:

  ```
  >>> max_cash(0, 1, [2 ** i for i in range(10)], [float('inf')] * 10)
  512
  ```
- [Keegan Carruthers-Smith](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4128487/solving-buying-selling-optimization-problem/4128648#comment4464004_4128648) suggests this counter-example:

  ```
  >>> max_cash(1, 0, [2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2])
  1
  ```

  which is unsurprising since the selling price is always the same as the buying price, and so no profit can be made, and so you can't possibly end up with more cash than you started with.

Comment: Maybe you should just make it explicit, that each day you can either do one of 3 things: sell everything, buy as much as possible or do nothing.

Then you also need to say that it doesn't make sense to sell only a part of your stock or buy only using some of your money. Buying and selling on the same day is pointless as: S[i] ≤ B[i] .

Then you just need to give a reasonable argument why maximising money at the end of the day maximises profits at the end. Since this is a greedy algorithm.

Comment: I'm leaving proof of correctness as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Ok, after some more thought, I've realised the last bullet point is completely wrong. When selling you dont keep money you had on the previous day. And so on

Comment: Additionally, a friend of mine has a counter example that breaks all greedy algorithms I can think of: `S[i] = a^i` and `B[i] = inf` where `a` is some positive constant. This breaks naive greedies, because it's the best to sell on the last day (A greedy would sell ASAP) and you can't ever buy new stock. (assume the price of stock on the first day is finite and you have money to buy stock).

Comment: Applying my algorithm to your example, I find that G[i]=0 and C[i]=1 for all *i*. It's never right to buy goods, and there's nothing to sell since you have cash but no goods. Are you assuming some other initial condition?

Comment: I'm assuming the cost on the initial day is low (other days it's infinite) and you have enough cash to buy a few items.

Comment: With initial conditions of G[0]=1 and C[0]=0 (i.e. you start with goods but no cash) then I find C[i]=a^i and G[i]=1 for all *i*.

Comment: You're algorithm is wrong. It doesn't reduce stock when it sells it by taking second branch of `max(C[i-1], G[i-1]S[i])`.

Comment: A possible point of misunderstanding. When I say "C[i] represents the maximum cash you can hold at the end of day i", I mean that there is at least one buying/selling strategy that holds C[i] cash at the end of day *i*, and no buying/selling strategy that holds more cash at the end of that day. I don't mean that there is *one* strategy that achieves this maximum on every day: most likely, the maximum is achieved by a different strategy for each *i*.

Comment: When you say, "it doesn't reduce stock", you're misunderstanding how the algorithm works. By hypothesis, there is some buying/selling strategy that holds G[i-1] goods at the end of day i-1. So we could hold G[i-1]S[i] cash at the end of day i (by following that strategy until day i-1 and then selling on day i).

Comment: Gareth run your algorithm on B = {2, 2, 2} and S = {2, 2, 2}. You should notice that G[i] is always 0 and C[i] is always 1. Clearly this is the wrong answer.

Comment: Oops, someone just pointed out that the answer is actually one since you can never buy. I am retarded sorry :P

Comment: I get G[1] = max(0, 1/2) = ½ and thereafter G[i] = ½, C[i] = 1.  Since the buying price and the selling price are always the same, no profit can be made, so you can't have any more cash at the end than you started with.

Comment: Any more counter-examples? Bring 'em on!

Comment: Gareth, that was a counter-example. How can you buy half an item?

Comment: Ok I actually put some proper thought in now. It is broken. B = {2, 3}, S = {2, 3}. You end up with C[2] = 1.5, even though you never have enough money to buy an item.

Comment: I'm assuming that the "goods" can be considered to be continuous for the purposes of the problem. (Think of a commodities market, or buying and selling shares, when your bankroll is large compared with the unit price.)

Comment: "How can you buy half an item?" Next thing you know, you'll be complaining that I haven't taken into account shipping fees and warehousing costs. Have you guys never heard of abstraction? :)

Answer (score 0):

just modifying previous recurrence.

```
C[i]: cash we can have at end of the day i.
C[i] = max(C[i-1],(S[i]-B[i])*G[i]);
```

where

```
G[i] is unit of good we can afford to buy.
G[i]=floor(C[i-1]/B[i])
```